# Precision of div in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select 15000000.0000000000000 / 6060802.6136561442650
```

gives `2.47491973525125848`

How can I get `2.4749197352512584803724193507358`?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think there is any built-in data type in SQL Server that has that level of precision.  It is a bit hard to understand why such precision is necessary, but if you have a problem like that, Postgres supports a very wide range of precisions.

Comment: where are you getting `03724193507358` from?the result of the division is what you get

Comment: @vkp from the windows calculator

Comment: @Gordon Linoff the decimal data type supports precision up to 38 digits

Comment: But it needs to represent the 15,000,000, so that is 8 digits to the left of the decimal place and 31 digits to the right (unless I miscounted).

Answer (score 3):

You can't, because of the result rules for determining precision and scale.  In fact, your scale is so large that there's no way to shift the result (ie, specifying no scale for the left operand).

First...

> The decimal data type supports precision up to 38 digits

... but "precision" here means the **total** number of digits.  Which, yes, your result should fit, but the engine won't shift things for you.  The [relevant rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) is:

```
Operation  Result precision                     Result scale *  
e1 / e2    p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)   max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)

* The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. 
  When a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is
  reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated.
```

.... you're running afoul of the last note there.  Here, let's run the numbers.

- Your operands have precisions (total digits) of 21 and 20 (p1 and p2, respectively)
- Your operands have scales (digits after the decimal) of 13 (s1 and s2)

So:

```
21 - 13 + 13 + max(6, 13 + 20 + 1) <- The bit in max is the scale, too
21 + max(6, 34)
21 + 34
= 55, with a scale of 34
```

... except `55 > 38`.  So the number of digits needs to be reduced.  Which, because digits become less significant as the value gets smaller, are dropped from the scale (which also reduces the precision):

```
55 - 38 = 17 <- difference
55 - 17 = 38 <- final precision
34 - 17 = 17 <- final scale
```

Now, if we count the number of digits from the answer it gives you, `.47491973525125848`, you'll get 17 digits.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can store decimal numbers with a maximum precision of 38.

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(38,37), 15000000.0000000000000 / 6060802.6136561442650)
AS TestValue brings 2.4749197352512584800000000000000000000.
```

Comment: Yes, but the `CONVERT` is happening _after_ the result is calculated, so the truncation can't be avoided.  You're trying to convert to a double and get the fractional result of integer math (1 / 2), essentially.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a pattern in the first parameter, you may save some precision with re-formulation such as

```
 select 1000000  * (15 / 6060802.6136561442650)
```

I can't test it in sql-server, I have only Oracle available and I get

```
 2,47491973525125848037241935073575410941
```

Comment: [Are you sure about that](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/8755/0)?  What version of Oracle?  Oracle also, like SQL Server, only supports 38 digits of precision in it's `NUMBER` type - you're showing **39**.    Also, note that, unlike "pure" mathematics where pulling out operands is largely a non-issue, this can (and currently _does_) generate different results with computers (the trailing 8 is being dropped).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse  This is *Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production*, both the original query and the modified one return this same result. So possible Oracle implements different rules as described in your answer fro MS server. (I have no explanation for the 39 scale and I guess there is some additional formating in fiddle). My idea was simple to minimize the loss in scale by pulling out - of course this may lead to a different result; here to a larger precision. And you are right without care this approach may lead to catastrophic results.